# Adding a font to a jasper report

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I have a problem with fonts in jasper report, this is my code:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#E36C0A"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <font size="12" pdfFontName="../../css/custom/fonts/amrgarab.TTF"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{centre}.getShortName().get($P{locale})]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Ok, the problem is that it writes but not using the font amrgarab.TTF

I read a lot about this, and I don't want to "install" in the server, I add the font to my project, can I do that? If I can do that, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a bit late answere XD, but now you have an oficial simple guide on how you could do this steps by steps.

[GUIDE](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)

It tells you how to used it on a simple jasper report file, and then how to export and import it to be used on all reports.

Comment: better have a awnser in 4 year rather than nothing :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add the attribute `isPDFEmbedded="true"` to your font declaration. This should then embed the font into the PDF file (as long as the font you've referenced is available when the report is exported).

With the font embedded in the file, it will always be available to the reader, so there is no need to have the font installed on the machine. The only caveat is that it will make your PDF files bigger.

**EDIT**

In jasper report version 5,6 you should use [Font Extension](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/) to correctly embed and render font in **pdf** ([itext](/questions/tagged/itext)) see

[Checklist to render font in pdf using font extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values/34044441#34044441)

[Creating font extensions with iReport or JasperStudio Soft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport/33941102#33941102)

Comment: This method is deprecated, now you use Font Extensions... I suggest you update post with this info..

Comment: @PetterFriberg I rarely use jasper reports these days, so I don't know anything about Font Extensions. Perhaps you could add another answer with the details?

Comment: I have edit your post, to include notes on Font Extensions, with link to accepted solutions on SO, I hope it is useful. (If you don't like feel free to roll back)